# Switching ip while parsing the site with ruby mechanize

Tags: ruby, ip, mechanize

Is there any way to change, or hide send request ip, while i'm parsing a website with my ruby mechanize program? To avoid bun from site server.

I've seen sites changing ip-adresses, like this http://www.newipnow.com/ . But don't figure how to use it in my program.

Here is my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'logger'

Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8

agent = Mechanize.new do |a| 
    a.ssl_version, 
    a.verify_mode = 'SSLv3', 
    OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE, a.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'
end

authrization = agent.get("http://vk.com/")
vk_form = authrization.forms.first
vk_form.email = 'myaccount'
vk_form.pass = 'mypassword'
authrization = agent.submit(vk_form, vk_form.buttons.first)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set a proxy like this:

```
agent.set_proxy host, port, user, pass
```

Comment: And what proxy server is better to use? Tor?